# Hadoop Multiple Outputs

Tags: java, hadoop

I wrote some hadoop code to read the mapped file and split it into chunks and write it to many files as follows:

```
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<IntWritable, Text> 
output,Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
String line = value.toString();
    int totalLines = 2000;
int lines = 0;
    int fileNum = 1;
String[] linesinfile = line.split("\n");
    while(lines<linesinfile.length) {
        // I do something like, if lines = totalLines, {
        output.collect(new IntWritable(fileNum), new    
            Text(linesinfile[lines].toString()));
        fileNum++;
        lines = 0;
        }
    lines++;
   }
}
```

In reduce, I do:

```
public void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterator<Text> values,
OutputCollector<IntWritable, Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
     while(values.hasNext()){
    output.collect(key, values.next());
}
}
```

My MultiFile class is as follows:

```
public class MultiFileOutput extends MultipleTextOutputFormat<IntWritable, Text> {

protected String generateFileNameForKeyValue(IntWritable key, Text content, String 
            fileName) {
    return key.toString() + "-" + fileName;
}
}
```

In main, I say:

```
    conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
    conf.setOutputFormat(MultiFileOutput.class);
```

apart from setting the OutKey/Value Class etc.

What am I doing wrong ? My output directory is always empty.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program looks a bit complex. If the purpose is to split the file into multiple files then it can be done in a couple of ways. There is no Need for a Map and Reduce job, just a Map job would be enough.

- Use o.a.h.mapred.lib.NLineInputFormat to read N lines at a time to the mapper from the input and then write those N lines to a file.
- Set the dfs.blocksize to the required file size while uploading the file, then each mapper will process one InputSplit which can be written to a file.

Comment: Thank You. Actually I was under the misconception that hadoop only sets as many mappers as the number of input files!(i am just starting out with hadoop.) Now I have set the numMapTasks to 5000.